# Save multiple variable from multiple forms

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
<?php

    echo '<fieldset><form action="gerer_adherents.php" method="post" >
        <h3>Identification pour gérer les adhérents :<br></h3>

    Hôte :<input type="text"  name="hote"/><br>
    BDD :<input type="text" name="bdd"/><br>
    Utilisateur :<input type="text" name="user"/><br>
    Mot de passe :<input type="text" name="password"/><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="validation" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="bouton" value="Envoyer" /></fieldset>';


    $host     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hote');
    $database = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bdd');
    $user     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    if (isset($host) && isset($database) && isset($user) && isset($password)) {
    try 
    {
        //$base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=court;charset=utf8', "root", "");
        $base = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';charset=utf8', $user, $password);
        var_dump($host, $database, $user, $password);
    }
    catch (exception $e) {
        die('Erreur ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    echo ' 
        <form action="gerer_adherents.php" method="post">
        <h3>Ajouter une personne :<br></h3>
        Nom :<input type="text" name="nom"/><br>
        Prenom :<input type="text"  name="prenom"/><br>
        Date de naissance :<input type="date" name="date"/><br>
        Téléphone :<input type="text" name="tel"/><br>
        Ville :<input type="text" name="ville"/><br>
        Mail :<input type="text" name="mail"/><br>
        Login :<input type="text" name="login"/><br>
        Password :<input type="text" name="password2"/><br>
        Re-Password :<input type="text" name="repassword2"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="bouton2" value="Envoyer" /> 
        </form>';


    $nom         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nom');
    $prenom      = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prenom');
    $date        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date');
    $tel         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tel');
    $ville       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ville');
    $mail        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mail');
    $login       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login');
    $password2   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2');
    $repassword2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'repassword2');

    if (isset($nom) && isset($prenom) && isset($date) && isset($tel) && isset($ville) && isset($mail) && isset($login) && isset($password2) && isset($repassword2)) {
        if ($nom && $prenom && $date && $tel && $ville && $mail && $login && $password2 && $repassword2) {
            if ($password2 == $repassword2) {

                var_dump($nom, $prenom, $date, $tel, $ville, $mail, $login, $password2);
                var_dump($host, $database, $user, $password);

                $base->exec("INSERT INTO adherent (`nom`, `prenom`, `date`, `tel`, `ville`, `mail`,`login`, `password`) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$date','$tel','$ville','$mail','$login','$password2')");
                $base->exec("CREATE USER '$login'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password2';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `court`.* TO '$login'@'localhost';");
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('Adhérent crée, redirection en cours....')window.location.href='administration.php';</SCRIPT><NOSCRIPT><a href='administration.php'>Adhérent crée, cliquez-ici, si vous n'êtes pas redirigé.</a></NOSCRIPT>");

            } else {
                echo "les 2 password doivent etre identique";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Veuillez saisir tous les champs";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
?>
   </body>
```

I've wrote this piece of code that allows me to connect to a MySql database, which consists of two forms (at least for the connection process).

The first one is for the connection to the database, and the second one for the execution of the query.

My problem, is that i'm able to connect with the hard coded value

```
$base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=court;charset=utf8', "root", "");
```

but if i want to connect with this line, it seems that the query doesn't work

```
$base = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8', $user, $password);
```

The value of the first form are just wiped when I try to send a query from the second form, so I don't know how to keep the values that were part of the input in the first form.

Comment: Can you close the first <form> and retry !

Comment: I did not understand why you want to make dynamic connection (ie login/pwd) to the database (you will have a big security issue)

Comment: "The value of the first form are just wiped when I try to send a query from the second form". This is normal. HTTP is _stateless_. If you want to persist the values you have to save them somewhere yourself. Where you save them depends on your requirements. For example it could be in the session, in a database, in a file (all server-side), in a cookie or localstorage (browser-side). But then again, why don't you just use one single form to capture all the information at once? Then there only needs to be one request and the user only needs to submit the form once. Easier all round.

Comment: A side point: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using standard PHP/mysql libraries. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.